# Namespace 'Electron.CrossProcessExports' has no exported member 'Remote

Tags: angular, electron, electron-forge

I'm new to Electronjs[image].

```
Error: node_modules/ngx-electron/lib/electron.service.d.ts:17:31 - error TS2694: Namespace 'Electron.CrossProcessExports' has no exported member 'Remote'.

17     readonly remote: Electron.Remote;
```

I hope anyone here, understands with this and is able to solve this. thank you! because my goal is to connect ipcMain, using ipcRenderer that I triggered on Angular Services.

Comment: please were you able to resolve this? if yes please how?

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search lead me to the issues section of the repository, and [one issue in particular](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron/issues/71).

The user, named **andelz**, gave a pretty good answer regarding what might be wrong.
By trial and error, I found a working solution that still contains no vulnerabilities (as of the moment of writing):

```
"ngx-electron": "2.2.0",
"electron": "13.6.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be the electron version. If you are following the steps from this url https://buddy.works/tutorials/building-a-desktop-app-with-electron-and-angular on how to build an electron application with angular, ensure to install electron v5.0.6

Answer (score 1):

Go to the node_modules/ngx-electron/lib/electron.service.d.ts and comment the line -> readonly remote: Electron.Remote;

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is found here https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron/issues/71#issuecomment-1059796649

I went into ./node_modules/ngx-electron/lib/electron.service.d.ts and comment out this line:

// readonly remote: Electron.Remote;

It compiled fine, and using axious for http, rest, google access and authentication all my remote issues were handled.

Note that if you update the module you will have to reload it, or do a branch of this and use that instead.